# Decrease value in database on button click with web-service

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, visual-studio, web-services

What i'm trying to do is to decrease the value in my database depending on which button the visitor presses. the database has values of different fruits in it. I have buttons with different values that need to be removed. I have connected the database but i don't know how i would remove values depending on which button is pressed.

Here are the buttons

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Here is how the database looks like

```
LagerrTable (database name)
id (Primary key)
Frukt
Antal (the value i want to remove from)
```

The database is connected to a web-service which is connected to a website. So basically i want to decrease value in the database depending on which button is pressed.

```
FruktReference.LagServiceClient Lklient = new FruktReference.LagServiceClient();
```

Comment: What library do you use to connect to database? I don't know C# at all, but is there really only one canonical way to do it?

Comment: @PawełKordowski What do you mean by library? i'm a beginner but it's a LINQ database

Comment: could you inclue a code that you use to connect to db?

Comment: @PawełKordowski I'll put it in the question above

Comment: @PawełKordowski No its not

Comment: so why google does not know about it?

Comment: @PawełKordowski Because i'm a beginner and i would like some help i dont fully understand all the codes. If u have a good tutorial or a link u are more than welcome to send it.

Comment: what is FruktReference.LagServiceClient?